# i have a simple HTML site and want to restrict its some pages via php login

Tags: php, html, authentication, restriction

The following is the HTML of the page that I want to restrict for regular users.
When someone tries to access this page then he/she must be logged in to view the details of the page. Please guide in this regards. How can I do that?

```
<head>
<title>Welcome to ULTRATEC</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Cufon -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myradpro.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')('h4')('div.menu li');
</script>
<!-- flash script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flash_detect.v1.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="rss"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logomain.png" width="218" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="search">
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <span>
        <input name="q" type="text" class="keywords" id="textfield" maxlength="50" value="Search..." />
        </span>
        <input name="b" type="image" src="images/search.gif" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="205" height="88" border="0" alt="logo" /></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="active"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="inquiry.html"><span>Inquiry form</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    <!-- start slideshow -->
    <div class="flash_slider">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0',
        'width', '100%',
        'height', '400',
        'src', 'piecemakerNoShadow',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_de',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'true',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'noscale',
        'wmode', 'transparent',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'piecemakerNoShadow',
        'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
        'name', 'piecemakerNoShadow',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'piecemakerNoShadow',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
</script>
</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <!-- end #slideshow -->
    <div class="click_blog">
      <div class="clr"></div></div>

  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="body_resize">
      <div class="right">
        <h2>About Us<br /></h2>
          <div class="left"><a href="inquiry.html"><img src="images/online-order.png" border="0" /></a></div>
        <p>The creation ultra tec dates back to 2001. The company has significantly and speedly grown to its current stature. We firmly and sincerely believe in quality. We reliably cater to various industrial sectors. Our major focus revolnes around the following: -</p>
<div>
<ul>
<li><strong>Strapping Solutions</strong></li>
<li><strong>Strapping Tools</strong></li>
<li><strong>Gluing Tachnology</strong></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><strong>Labelling & Packaging Glues</strong></li>
<li><strong>Case Palletising</strong></li>
<li><strong>Metal Marking Solutions</strong></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><strong>Screen Printing Mesh</strong></li>
<li><strong>Screen Printing Blades</strong></li>
</ul>
</div><div class="clr"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use session or cookies to do this. Store a login token in either session or cookie then check if user is logged in before rendering that page, else redirect to login page

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

If the session is set, he's logged in. When he logs out, destroy the session.

Set the session when you login:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Then on the restricted page do something like this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  //redirect to where people who are not logged in should be.
} else {
  //access to the page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have somthing like this:
Login page:

```
<?php 
session_start() ;
(Here you check login data .If this login data is ok set username on session)
$_SESSION['username']= $username;
?>
```

On user page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "Hello ".$_SESSION['username'];
}
else
{
die("You don't have acces on this page");'
}

?>
```